# Bootstrap 3: how to generate a new block when a dropdown item is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, dropdown

I'm using Bootstrap 3 on Rails 3 (Haml == HTML && Coffee == JS), and I'm rather a newbie in JavaScript.

I'm looking for using Bootstrap's dropdown menu, for when I click on a li>a, I would like it to generate a new block, with the amount associated to the currency listed.

The Bootstrap dropdown looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown currencies">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Select a currency
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu currencies-list" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li class="euro"><a href="#">Price in €</a></li>
        <li class="dollar"><a href="#">Price in $</a></li>
        <li class="pound"><a href="#">Price in £</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is what could the list of the amounts look like:

```
<ul class="prices-list">
    <li class="euro">6.50€</li>
    <li class="dollar">$4.96</li>
    <li class="pound">£5.58</li>
</ul>
```

How should I link these prices for them to appear only when the associated li>a of the Bootstrap dropdown menu is selected? 
(I mean, if "Price in €" is selected in the dropdown, display - only - the amount/price in €.)

Also, I'd like the $ amount to be selected and displayed by default.

I think it's trivial, however I've googled my question for an hour without finding anything...

Don't hesitate to answer in Haml*Coffee if you like, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do some simple hide/show

```
$('.currencies-list a').click(function(){
 var class = $(this).parent().attr('class');//get the class of the currency selected
 $('.prices-list').find('li').hide();//hide all prices 
 $('.prices-list').find('li.'+class).show();//show only the price for the selected currency 
})
```